# Computing cohomology of certain sheaf on a $K3$ surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be a vector bundle over a $K3$ surface $X$ which is globally generated away from finitely many points,then I want to show that $H^1((H^0(E)^* \otimes  \mathcal O_X) /E^*) =0 $.Let's denote the sheaf inside cohomology notation by $\mathcal F$

My guess : By Serre duality we have,  $ (H^1(\mathcal F))^* = Ext^1(\mathcal F, \mathcal O_X)$ .

I hope that the last expression is trivial because of the the following proposition in Hathshorne's book (page $237$, proposition $6.10(b)$), which says the following : for a ring $A$ and for a $A$ module $M$, we have $M$ is projective iff  $Ext^1(M,N) =0$ for all $A$ module $N$.

Doubts : I am nowhere using the facts $(1)$ $X$ is a$K3$ surface ,i.e $H^1(X, O_X)=0$ and $(2)$ $E$ is globally generated away from finitely many points.

Please correct me if the argument that I have given is wrong.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your argument, but here is an argument.

You have the exact sequence $0\to E^*\to H^0(E)^*\otimes O_X\to F\to 0$. Taking cohomologies, you get $H^1(H^0(E)^*\otimes O_X)\to H^1(F)\to H^2(E^*)\to H^2(H^0(E)^*\otimes O_X)$. The first term is zero since $H^1(O_X)=0$. The last map is an inclusion, since by dulity, it is dual to $H^0(H^0(E)\otimes O_X)\to H^0(E)$, which is an isomorphism. Thus, $H^1(F)=0$.

Comment: ,thanks for the answer. So here perhaps we are using that $Hom((H^0(E))^* \otimes \mathcal O_X) , \mathcal O_X) =(H^0(E))^*$

Comment: @HARRY I am just using that the Serre dual of $H^2(H^0(E)^*\otimes O_X)$ is $H^0(H^0(E)\otimes O_X)$ since $K_X=O_X$.

Comment: I think instead of directly applying Serre duality for projective scheme (i.e Theorem $7.6(a)$ Harthshorne) you are applying the corollary $7.7$ which states: Let $X$ be a projective Cohen-Macaulay scheme of equidimen-
sion $n$ over $\mathbb K$. Then for any locally free sheaf $\mathcal F$ on X there are natural
isomorphisms
$H^i(\mathcal F) \cong  (Η^{n-i}(\mathcal F^* \otimes ω_X^0))'$.